# Detec mouse wheel events in REACT

Tags: reactjs

im detecting mouse wheel direction with the following code:

```
const onWheelHandler = e => {
        const dir = e.deltaY;
        if (dir < 0) {
            // up
        } else if (dir > 0) {
            // down
        }
    }
```

with use of a div:

```
<div onWheel={e => onWheelHandler(e)}>
    // content
</div
```

I want it to run only once per movment no matter how long was the movement of the wheel.

right now this function execute every wheel movement, meaning if I keep moving the wheel long time but in the same action it's just keep executing the function and thats a problem.

HELP ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a state to save the last mouvement.

```
const [lastMouvement, setLastmouvement] = useState(null);
const onWheelHandler = e => {
    const dir = e.deltaY;
    if(lastMouvement === dir){
        return;
    }
    setLastmouvement(dir);
    
    if (dir < 0) {
        // up
    } else if (dir > 0) {
        // down
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working but only on the first movement, cause when i try to move the same direction again but after a pause it's not working at all cause its the same direction..